# Eclipse RCP for multiple user with one copy . error about osgi

Tags: configuration, osgi, rcp, ini, multiple-users

I build a rcp use osgi which can work well when just a user use one of copy. but i want to change it to different linux user share one of copy(read only for all user ) ,but osgi need a "./confiurationg" with writable .  There is a best way to resolve if ?

Comment: See [Eclipse Multi-User Installs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html)

Comment: I have add                                                                                                    -vmargs
-Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=true
-Dosgi.sharedConfiguration.area=configuration
-Dosgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.<rcpname>/configuration
-Dosgi.instance.area=@user.home/.<rcpname>/workspace                            in my <rcpname>.ini . that have change the configuration area to user's home dir   but there will a error  like "unable to acquire application service " in  some time   ,